# c# - importing xml file

Tags: c#, xml, listview, import

In my project I have got a listview filled with contacts which are stored in a XML file.

This is the connection between the two of these and basically this is how the contacts are loaded:

Please note that first function is called on form loading:

```
void LoadContacts()
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string phonebook_path = path + "\\Phonebook\\Contacts.xml";
        if (!File.Exists(phonebook_path))
        {
            XmlTextWriter xW = new XmlTextWriter(phonebook_path, Encoding.UTF8);
            xW.WriteStartElement("People");
            xW.WriteEndElement();
            xW.Close();
        }
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(phonebook_path);
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("People/Person"))
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
            p.Hometown = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Hometown").InnerText;
            p.Address = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Address").InnerText;
            p.Birthday = DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(xNode.SelectSingleNode("Birthday").InnerText));
            p.Phone = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Phone").InnerText;
            p.Email = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Email").InnerText;
            p.AdditionalInfo = xNode.SelectSingleNode("AdditionalInfo").InnerText;
            people.Add(p);
            listView1.Items.Add(p.Name);
            UserCount();
        }
    }
```

and then the other one on form closing:

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string phonebook_path = path + "\\Phonebook\\Contacts.xml";
        xDoc.Load(phonebook_path);
        XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("People");
        xNode.RemoveAll();
        foreach (Person p in people)
        {
            XmlNode xTop = xDoc.CreateElement("Person");
            XmlNode xName = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
            XmlNode xHometown = xDoc.CreateElement("Hometown");
            XmlNode xAddress = xDoc.CreateElement("Address");
            XmlNode xBirthday = xDoc.CreateElement("Birthday");
            XmlNode xPhone = xDoc.CreateElement("Phone");
            XmlNode xEmail = xDoc.CreateElement("Email");
            XmlNode xAdditionalInfo = xDoc.CreateElement("AdditionalInfo");
            xName.InnerText = p.Name;
            xHometown.InnerText = p.Hometown;
            xAddress.InnerText = p.Address;
            xBirthday.InnerText = p.Birthday.ToFileTime().ToString();
            xPhone.InnerText = p.Phone;
            xEmail.InnerText = p.Email;
            xAdditionalInfo.InnerText = p.AdditionalInfo;
            xTop.AppendChild(xName);
            xTop.AppendChild(xHometown);
            xTop.AppendChild(xAddress);
            xTop.AppendChild(xBirthday);
            xTop.AppendChild(xPhone);
            xTop.AppendChild(xEmail);
            xTop.AppendChild(xAdditionalInfo);
            xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xTop);
        }

        xDoc.Save(phonebook_path);
        Sync();
        SetStartup();
    }
```

I have got an option to import the XML file via method Import() which is called when a button is clicked.

```
void Import()
    {
        Main f1 = new Main();
        OpenFileDialog BrowseFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (BrowseFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.ImportPath = BrowseFile.FileName;
        }
        string fileName = "Contacts.xml";
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string sourcePath = Properties.Settings.Default.ImportPath;
        string targetPath = path + "\\Phonebook\\";
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, destFile, true); 
        MessageBox.Show("Contacts have successfully been imported. Please restart your application in order changes to take effect!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

...Importing is performed perfectly which means I can see the copied XML file in the right place, but when I close the application, all of a sudden XML file turns into previous state somehow which means changes didn't take effect - when I load the app again, there will be no imported contacts.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Little confused why you bother loading the file in the form close event.

Comment: The code (in the Closing) is putting the data back into some "previous state". It's not happening automatically.

Comment: @user2864740: I am not retarded, I figured out that on my own. The question is what can I do to solve that issue.

Comment: To determine if it is your code doing this you need to set some breakpoints in your code and make observations.

Comment: "..which means changes didn't take effect.." well, what changes and *why* would they be saved (or take effect)? You're only saving once, btw.

Comment: @user2864740: Please tell me what changes do you think I am talking about when the whole question is about importing contacts? What do you think, ha? I would say, changes in the contact list! And they certainly have to be saved because the simple fact is that the changes would be lost if they were not saved. Simple as that. Maybe you should shut up instead of posting unconstructive comments and being a smartass here. If you don't feel like helping, please do not make it harder. Thank you.

Comment: @Dan-o: Yes man, it is the code for sure. I am not running any other applications that could affect this one.

Comment: Then use your debugger.  You have all the tools you need to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your Import method, add

```
people.Clear()
LoadContacts();
```

What was happening was you copied the new xml file and replaced the old, but your `people` list still had the original xml's information. Then, when the form was closing, the new file's contents was replaced by the original information, making it look like the file had un-coppied or something. The solution is to clear the list, and then read the new file like the program had just started. Using this you also won't have to restart the app. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt you be calling your `LoadContacts()` at the end of your `Import()` method? From what I can tell,

- Form loads -> Loads data from your contacts xml into your listview object.
- Import is clicked -> overwrites your current contacts xml with new contacts xml (But does NOT update your listview/people object)
- Form closes -> saves your `people` object details (which still only contains your old contacts xml details) into your contacts xml, hence putting it back to what it was when the form loaded.

Although, looking at the LoadContacts() method, you will have to clear the `people` and `listView1.Items` lists at the start of the method if you wanted to call it multiple times and not have imported contacts appended to the original list. If this is desired behavior then it should be fine as is.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, you completely understood the problem. Anyway, the problem now is that LoadContacts() is located in **Main** form and in this case I am gonna be trying to call it from another form (**Settings** form) and this is not possible, unless I declare it as public or sth (I really do not know how to do that since I am new to c# as you can see).